# Remove leading zeros from text box

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I have the following code:

```
    private void txtDiscount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtDiscount.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            txtDiscount.Text = "0";
            txtDiscount.Select(txtDiscount.Text.Length, 0);
        }
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d+\.?\d{0,2}$");
        if (!regex.IsMatch(txtDiscount.Text))
        {
            txtDiscount.Text = txtDiscount.Text.Substring(0, txtDiscount.Text.Length - 1);
            txtDiscount.Select(txtDiscount.Text.Length, 0);
        }
    }

    private void txtDiscount_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtDiscount.Text.Equals("0"))
        {
            txtDiscount.Text = e.KeyChar.ToString();
            txtDiscount.Select(txtDiscount.Text.Length, 0);
        }
    }
```

To sum up, my code above makes sure that the user enters a number, and only a number. Optionally, with 2 decimal places.

If the user hits backspace repeatedly until all characters are cleared, I want my TextBox to at least, contain a "0".
My problem is that, for example, my textbox only contains the text "0" and the user presses on a key (representing a number 1 to 9), I want that "0" to be removed and replaced with the numerical key pressed.

For example:
TextBox contains: "0".
User presses 2.
TextBox should now contain "2", not "02".
However, with my code above, my TextBox shows the string "22" instead. It doubles which numerical key was pressed. If 3 was pressed, it'll output "33".

Comment: You could convert the content of the textbox into an integer (or float) and then back to string again. This process would kill every leading zero. But there is maybe a better way in C# I don't know :P.

Comment: It's a Windows Form.

Comment: You can also use TrimStrart to remove any leading character.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx):

> *The `MaskedTextBox` class is an enhanced `TextBox` control that supports a declarative syntax for accepting or rejecting user input.*

I think that does what you need.

You can change the mask dynamically to suit the specific input. See this related answer: [dynamically growing masked text- box](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/60879cfb-be88-4ddf-9eca-95b1d0618dd9/dynamically-growing-masked-text-box)

Comment: of course masked textBox look like solve problem, but there is no pattern stop leading with zero. it must handle textChanged again.

Comment: I'm validating the input from 0 to 100, with 2 decimal places which are optional. I originally wanted to use a MaskedTextBox but to input the value 2.25, I have to see do it like: "002.25". Or is it me who doesn't know how to use it. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: I don't know if whether it can be done by changing mask, depending on text inputted. I.e . Similar to the solution in this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/60879cfb-be88-4ddf-9eca-95b1d0618dd9/dynamically-growing-masked-text-box

Answer (score 0):

Keypress even automatically adds pressed key to the container(textbox), so to fix try removing

txtDiscount.Text = e.KeyChar.ToString();

Comment: That of does not allow me to see a decimal dot on my textbox when I press it. I'm thinking this concerns the IsMatch if statement.

Comment: its not answer of this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    var entry = e.KeyChar.ToString();
    int output;
    if (entry != "\b" && !int.TryParse(entry, out output))
        e.Handled = true;
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var entry = ((TextBox) sender).Text;
    if (entry == "0")
        ((TextBox) sender).Text = "";
}
```

keep it simple. keyPress raised before textChanged. handle if user pressed unwanted key handle it with keyPress. after if user pressed first 0 dont accept in textChanged.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void txtDiscount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtDiscount.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            txtDiscount.Text = "0";
            txtDiscount.Select(txtDiscount.Text.Length, 0);
        }
        if (!txtDiscount.Text.Equals("0"))
        {
            txtDiscount.Text = txtDiscount.Text.TrimStart('0');
            txtDiscount.Select(txtDiscount.Text.Length, 0);
        }
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d+\.?\d{0,2}$");
        if (!regex.IsMatch(txtDiscount.Text))
        {
            txtDiscount.Text = txtDiscount.Text.Substring(0, txtDiscount.Text.Length - 1);
            txtDiscount.Select(txtDiscount.Text.Length, 0);
        }
    }
```

I followed beatles1962's suggestion, so thank you, sir. It was quite a problem for me where to put it at first. But yeah, I think this solves my question pretty much. Thanks for everybody's help.